# mysql Query slow on view for search

Tags: mysql, sql

Our search is very slow on view. we can't define index on view.. Please help how we can improve this .. Below Query took 33.3993 sec.

```
SELECT 
     `v_cat_pro`.`product_id`, `v_cat_pro`.`msrp`, 
FROM 
     `v_prod_cat` AS `v_cat_pro`
WHERE 
     (product_status="1" and msrp >0 AND (search_text = 'de') )
ORDER BY 
     `msrp` ASC LIMIT 50
```

Explain query result

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  cat_product     index   catproducts_product_id,category_product_index   category_product_index  8   NULL    941343  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  dept    eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   newdhf.cat_product.category_id  1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  team    eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   newdhf.dept.parent_id   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  league  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   newdhf.team.parent_id   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  product     eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   newdhf.cat_product.product_id   1   Using where
```

CREATE 
     ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED VIEW `v_prod_cat` AS
select
    `dept`.`id` AS `dept_id`,`team`.`short_name` AS `shortteamname`,`team`.`url` AS `team_url`,`team`.`id` AS `team_id`,`league`.`id` AS `league_id`,`product`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`product`.`product_status` AS `product_status`,`product`.`upload_image_l` AS `upload_image_l`,`dept`.`name` AS `department`,`team`.`name` AS `team`,`league`.`name` AS `league`,`product`.`title` AS `title`,`cat_product`.`product_url` AS `product_url`,`product`.`discount` AS `discount`,`product`.`discount_start_date` AS `discount_start_date`,`product`.`discount_end_date` AS `discount_end_date`,`product`.`extra_discount` AS `extra_discount`,`product`.`extra_discount_start_date` AS `extra_discount_start_date`,`product`.`extra_discount_end_date` AS `extra_discount_end_date`,`product`.`global_alt_tag` AS `global_alt_tag`,`product`.`msrp` AS `msrp`,`product`.`cost` AS `cost`,`product`.`vendor_id` AS `vendor_id`,if((`cat_product`.`is_default` > 0),1,0) AS `is_default`,

concat(`league`.`name`,_utf8' ',`team`.`name`,_utf8' ',`dept`.`name`,_utf8' ',replace(replace(replace(replace(`product`.`title`,'$leaguename',`league`.`name`),'$teamname',`team`.`name`),'$shortteamname',`team`.`short_name`),'$departmentname',`dept`.`name`),' ',`product`.`sku_code`,_utf8' ',replace(replace(replace(replace(`product`.`site_search_keyword`,'$leaguename',`league`.`name`),'$teamname',`team`.`name`),'$shortteamname',`team`.`short_name`),'$departmentname',`dept`.`name`)) AS `search_text`

from 
   ((((`categories` `dept` join `categories` `team` on(((`team`.`id` = `dept`.`parent_id`) and (`team`.`category_type` = _utf8'team')))) join `categories` `league` on(((`league`.`id` = `team`.`parent_id`) and (`league`.`category_type` = _utf8'league')))) join `category_products` `cat_product` on((`cat_product`.`category_id` = `dept`.`id`))) join `products` `product` on((`product`.`product_id` = `cat_product`.`product_id`))) where (`dept`.`category_type` = _utf8'department') 
order by 
      `dept`.`id` desc;

Comment: Usually full text search is the answer for slow queries and text search... Otherwise don't you need like maybe instead of the `= 'des'` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "we can't define index on view"? Can you not just define the index on the table the view is referencing?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for reply, the referencing table is innoDB, and the field in view "search_text" is manipulated from multiple joins in the view.. let me know how can define index on them.. As I explain the query above..

Answer (score 0):

If you add an index to your 'v_prod_cat' table on the columns that you are searching on then this should help speed up your view.

Comment: 'v_prod_cat' this is actually a view, we can't define index @Simon

Comment: 'v_prod_cat' this is actually a view, we can't define index @Lajos Veres

Comment: As that is a view then the tables that are used within that view may not have the best indexing applied.  Try running through all the tables within this view to see if they have been set up correctly.

Comment: Something I have also noticed on some of my queries in the past, when you are converting the collation of values within the queries (using _utf8 to set the collation of the string for instance) then it can slow it down a bit.  Can you change the collation of the tables or text you are passing?